# то,то. Синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

*То истиной дышит всё в ней, то всё в ней притворно и сложно.*

Нужно составить схему предложения.
То[Дышит], то[]... Тут уже проблемы, не могу определить сказуемое. По идее, *притворно* и *сложно* - дополнения с союзом "и". 
(Тема - сложносочинённые предложения с разделительными союзами.)

Comment: То истиной дышит..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все притворно и сложно - составное именное сказуемое. Только это не сложноподчиненное, а сложносочиненное.

Answer (score 3):

> То истиной дышит всё в ней, то всё в ней притворно и сложно. Нужно
>   составить схему предложения. То[Дышит],то[] и тут уже проблемы. Не
>   могу определить сказуемое, **по идее притворно и сложно дополнения**.

***Притворно*** и ***сложно*** -- однородные сказуемые, ***всё*** -- подлежащее.

Возможная схема:

*То [=  -], то [- = и =]*